# How do I use input if the user entered a char into an int?

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin

I have a code in which I read ints into a vector.

```
vector <int> v;

for (int i; cin >> i;){
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

and to end the loop, the user must enter '/'. How would I do that?
in other words, if the user enters a char into an int, how do I use the input?

Comment: If you want to read a line of input and then parse it, write code to do that. Instead, you've written code that only accepts an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `std::string` to read array of characters, compare the string if it equals to your desired string for termination of the sequence and if not, convert it to int

```
std::vector <int> v;
std::string buffer;

while(true){
   std::cin >> buffer;

   if(buffer == "/") break;

   v.push_back(std::stoi(buffer));
}
```

NOTE: if u try to enter characters that can't be converted there will be an error

for more reference check out:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Answer (score 0):

You just about need to read the individual chars (or strings) from the stream. Then determine whether it's actually a number or not. If it is, convert it (e.g., using `std::stoi`). If not, check whether it's the "quit" symbol, and if so go on to whatever else you need to do. If it's something else, you'd typically report the error, and if it's meant to be used interactively, probably give the user another chance to enter the right thing.